# Do file tests use `$_` or `_` in a given…when switch?

Tags: perl

When using [file test operators](http://p3rl.org/-X), the `stat()` results are cached in `_` so if you want to perform several tests you don't need to do more system calls.

```
if (-f $file_) {
  say 'readable' if -r _;
  say 'writable' if -w _;
}
```

If I use them in a [`given…when`](http://p3rl.org/syn#Switch-statements), do they use `_` or `$_`?

```
given ($file) {
  when (! -f) {}
  when (-r) {say 'readable';continue}
  when (-w) {say 'writable';continue}
  ....
}
```

I have the impression that this will use `$_`. Is that true? Also because `given…when` does not have default fall-through it is necessary to use `continue` in order to see other matches.

Probably this case is better resolved with `if`s and uses less typing than with the `given…when` approach. But it is too tempting to see if you can fit `given…when` when refactoring your software. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what it deparsed into:

```
sub {
    use warnings;
    use strict 'refs';
    BEGIN {
        $^H{'feature_unicode'} = q(1);
        $^H{'feature_say'} = q(1);
        $^H{'feature_state'} = q(1);
        $^H{'feature_switch'} = q(1);
    }
    my $file = shift @_;
    given ($file) {
        when (not -f $_) {
            ();
        }
        when (-r $_) {
            say 'readable';
            continue;
        }
        when (-w $_) {
            say 'writable';
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

So it doesn't show smart matching in the op codes.

Comment: silly me, obviously not! my focus was on $_ vs _ and I was not paying attention and put the ~~ because is the default test method for when, but here the test is the -r etc itself not ~~. I am editing the question removing the ~~

Answer (score 0):

The virtual filehandle `_` is never the default argument for a file test operator (not counting the stacked file tests that all operate of the same file, since only one of them has an argument). You have to use it explicitly to tell the file test to use the values from the last file stat.

`$_` is the default for most of the other file test operators, but not all of them.